# Holiday application on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried solve these tasks for a homework but I got stuck:

You will need to to create four functions:

1. Hotel cost - This function will take the number of nights as an argument and return a total cost (You can choose the price per a night)
2. Plane cost - This function will take the city you are flying to as an argument and return a cost for the flight (Hint: use if/else if statements in the function to retrieve a price based on the chosen city)
3. Car rental - This function will take the number of days  as an argument and return the total cost.
4. Holiday cost - This function will take three arguments, number of nights, city, and days.

Using these three arguments, you can call all three of the above functions with respective arguments and finally return a total cost for your holiday.

Print out the value of your Holiday function to see the result!

Try using your app with different combinations to show it’s compatibility
with different options

This is what I have so far:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 875

def plane_cost(city):
    ticket = 0
    while city != 4:
        if city == '1':
            ticket = 750
            break

        elif city == '2':
            ticket = 850
            break

        elif city == '3':
            ticket = 600
            break

        elif city == '4':
            print 'You have selected an invalid option'
        else:
            print 'You have selected an invalid option'

def car_rental(days):
    return days * 275

def holiday_cost(nights, city, days):
    nights = hotel_cost(nights)
    city = plane_cost(city)
    days = car_rental(days)
    return nights + city + days

hotel_cost(int(raw_input('How many nights will you be staying? ')))
plane_cost(raw_input('\n1. O.R. Tambo International\n2. Capetown International\n3. King Shaka International\nWhere you flying to? '))
car_rental(int(raw_input('How many days will you need a car for?: ')))
total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days)
print total
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Mengezi Dlomo-9897\intro to programming\Task 24\holiday.py", line 37, in <module> total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days) NameError: name 'nights' is not defined
```

Comment: What's the problem? This is far too broad.

Comment: holiday_cost is gives me an error.

Comment: error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Mengezi Dlomo-9897\intro to programming\Task 24\holiday.py", line 37, in <module>
    total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days)
NameError: name 'nights' is not defined

Comment: Well, it’s not, you read the number of night right into a function. You should save it first if you want to reuse it later.

Comment: You're not storing the results from the user input, i.e.`nights = int(raw_input('How many nights will you be staying? '))` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already call the 3 other functions inside holiday_cost. You don't need to call them multiple times.

Also ive made a few other helpful changes such as `while city > 3:` instead of `while city != 4:` in plane_cost() and I added a `return ticket` line at the end of plane_cost()

Also the line:
    elif city == '4':
        print 'You have selected an invalid option'
was unnecessary as city == '4' falls into the `else` condition.

Here is the final code:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 875

def plane_cost(city):
    ticket = 0
    while city > 3:
        if city == '1':
            ticket = 750
            break

        elif city == '2':
            ticket = 850
            break

        elif city == '3':
            ticket = 600
            break

        else:
            print 'You have selected an invalid option'

    return ticket

def car_rental(days):
    return days * 275

def holiday_cost(nights, city, days):
    nights = hotel_cost(nights)
    city = plane_cost(city)
    days = car_rental(days)
    return nights + city + days

nights = int(raw_input('How many nights will you be staying? '))
city = raw_input('\n1. O.R. Tambo International\n2. Capetown International\n3. King Shaka International\nWhere you flying to? ')
days = int(raw_input('How many days will you need a car for?: '))
total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days)
print total
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now bruv. I hate having to struggle with these tasks. It makes me feel like such an idiot. Thanks. One day I'll be an excellent programmer. P.S. The code works like a bomb

Comment: @ZeeDhlomo Haha, thanks for the comment, and dw you'll get there, I'm pretty new as well. Just been learning python for a few months and its my first language. Your code wasn't far off from the answer, just needed a few tweaks :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days)
```

but `nights, city, days` are not defined. You used those names to define the input parameters but that does not define those variables outside the functions where they are used.

In other words

```
def someFunction(inputP):
    #here inputP is defined
    ...
#her inputP is not defined
```

To return to your question you must assign the returned value to those variables:

```
nights = hotel_cost(int(raw_input('How many nights will you be staying? ')))
city = plane_cost(raw_input('\n1. O.R. Tambo International\n2. Capetown  International\n3. King Shaka International\nWhere you flying to? '))
days = car_rental(int(raw_input('How many days will you need a car for?: ')))
```

Since it is easy to get lost in Python I suggest using different names for variables in different scope: do not use `nights` for example in `hotel_cost` then twice in `holiday_cost` and then another time in the global scope.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the values you asked in variables:

```
nights=hotel_cost(int(raw_input('How many nights will you be staying? ')))
city=plane_cost(raw_input('\n1. O.R. Tambo International\n2. Capetown 
    International\n3. King Shaka International\nWhere you flying to? '))
days=car_rental(int(raw_input('How many days will you need a car for?: ')))
total = holiday_cost(nights, city, days)
```

Regards!